# Diffrence between extends from App and object contain main method in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wrote sample spark-scala program for creating list of json elements from dataframe. when i executed with main method it returns empty list but when i executed without object that extends app it returns list that contains records.
what is the difference between extends App and main method in scala object

```
object DfToMap {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
.appName("Rnd")
.master("local[*]")
.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
(8, "bat"),
(64, "mouse"),
(27, "horse")
).toDF("number", "word")

val json = df.toJSON
val jsonArray = new util.ArrayList[String]()
json.foreach(f => jsonArray.add(f))
print(jsonArray)
}
}
```

It will return empty list
But following program gives me list with records

```
object DfToMap extends App{
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
.appName("Rnd")
.master("local[*]")
.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
(8, "bat"),
(64, "mouse"),
(27, "horse")
).toDF("number", "word")

val json = df.toJSON
val jsonArray = new util.ArrayList[String]()
json.foreach(f => jsonArray.add(f))
print(jsonArray)

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Both snippets are not correct Spark programs, but one is just more incorrect than the other.

You've made two mistakes, both explained in the introductory Spark materials.

- Due to it's nature Spark doesn't support applications extending `App` - [Quick Start - Self-Contained Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications)

  > Note that applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly.
- Spark doesn't provide global shared memory therefore modifying global object is a closure is not supported - [Spark Programming Guide - Understanding Closures](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-)

Comment: thanks user10095367 . I trying to understand why the behavior of spark changes

Comment: Hey could you also explain [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76047885/does-sparkcontext-have-to-execute-in-main-only) if possible